# Wordpress & Advanced Custom Fields - Retrieving categories

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I seem to be having problems retrieving posts/attachments after connecting them to Woocommerce categories while using advanced custom fields.

I've tried using the advanced example as detailed [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/query-posts-custom-fields/) and this is as close as I can get using that example:

```
$images = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type'   => 'attachment',
  'meta_query'  => array(
    'relation'    => 'AND',
    array(
      'key'       => 'category',
      'value'     => array('12', '13'),
      'compare'   => 'IN'
    )              
   )
));
```

It's still not working and I'm not too sure why.

I've had a look at the db entry and the entry in question is:

```
meta_id      post_id      meta_key                 meta_value
  242          70         category      a:2:{i:0;s:2:"12";i:1;s:2:"13";}
```

Any help would be much appreciated, and thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

Update: Changed the 'post_type' to use the correct type. Still not working at the moment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution to the problem. Apparently I was using the wrong type of `compare` value and the actual value for the category had to have double quotes.

I found the sample code I needed [here](http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/).

Here's how the final solution looked like for me:

```
$images = get_posts(array(
  'numberposts' => -1,
  'post_type'   => 'attachment',
  'meta_query' => array(
    array(
      'key' => 'category',
      'value' => '"12"',
      'compare' => 'LIKE'
    )
  ),
));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your post type is labeled `attachments` but it should be `attachment`. Post type is singular.

Comment: Thank you for this. I've changed it to `attachment` but it still doesn't work at the moment.